# Left Align custom label with spaces along with items

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, enumerate, enumitem

I am trying to define a custom list that left aligns the label and then left aligns the items (at the same point in the page that is x from the longest label), so varying distance between the start of each item and its label).

[image: desired result]

I would also like the label to be bold font and have a ":" appended (without writing it out each time). When I use `parleft`, it seems to mess up when the label has spaces. How can I fix this overlapping text?

[image: text overlap]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newlist{detail}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[detail]{
    label=\textbf{}:
    leftmargin=*
}
\section*{My List}
\begin{detail}[align=parleft,labelsep=6em]
\item[A Label with five words] Thing 1
\item[Other] Thing 2
\end{detail}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use a simple `tabular`such as the ones in the following MWE? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\section*{My List}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l<{:}@{\hspace{2em}}l@{}}
A Label with five words & Thing 1\\
Other& Thing 2\\
\end{tabular}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}wl{4cm}<{:}l@{}}
A Label with five words & Thing 1\\
Other& Thing 2\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`

Comment: That seems like easier approach. How about bolding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The following two suggestions do currently not allow for linebreaks in both table columns. If you happen to need them, you might want to take a look at the `tabularx` package.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} 
\begin{document}  
\section*{My List}  
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}l<{:}@{\hspace{2em}}l@{}} % fixes space between left and right column
A Label with five words & Thing 1\\ 
Other& Thing 2\\ 
\end{tabular}  

\noindent 
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}wl{4.5cm}<{:}l@{}}  % fixed with first column
A Label with five words & Thing 1\\ 
Other& Thing 2\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

---

For longer entries in the first column, you could use `p{5cm}` instead of `wl{5cm}`. If you also want to make sure, the text is left aligned instead of justified, add `\raggedright\arraybackslash`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{array} 
\begin{document}  
 
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}<{:}l@{}}  % fixed with first column
A Label with five words A Label with five words & Thing 1\\ 
Other& Thing 2\\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't seem to wrap a long column entry into two rows with this solution (by inserting `p{wd}` as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/790944/6819862)? `\begin{tabular}){@{}>{\bfseries}wp{5cm}<{:}l@{}}` removes the column entirely?

Comment: @cpage: Remove the superfluous `)`. Also `w` can only be used in combination with `l`, `r`, or `c`. A corrected version of your suggestion would look like the following: `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}wp{5cm}<{:}l@{}}` Depending on the expected alignment (justified vs. left aligned), you might alternatively want to try `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries\raggedright\arraybackslash}wp{5cm}<{:}l@{}}`

Comment: @leandrils, appologies. That `)` was typo in comment. `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}wp{5cm}<{:}l@{}}` still removes the column but it works if you remove the`w` (i.e. `\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{5cm}<{:}l@{}}`

Comment: Sorry for the typo in my previous qcomment. The corrected version indeed does not include the `w`. I updated my answer accordingly.